# What exactly it means that functor in c++ have a state and other regular function doesnt have a state?

Tags: c++, stl, state, functor

I am new to STL concepts in C++, and when I am going through a functor I have a struct, at that point the functor has a state, whereas other regular functions don't have state. What does it actually mean?

So far, I saw info that says a functor has state so it can access and store the data of its class where the `operator()` is overloaded, and other regular functions only can access the parameters passed to it as it doesn't have state.

But look at my following code:

```
class MyFuncPtr
{
public:
    int a;

    int operator ()(int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
    
    MyFuncPtr(int val)
    {
        a = val;
    }
    
    int sum(int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!\n";

    MyFuncPtr obj(5);

    int c = obj(15);

    int d = obj.sum(15);
}
```

Here with both functor and normal function, I can do the same thing, so what exactly does the functor having a "state" mean?

Comment: `sum` isn't a function, it's a method just the same as `operator()` so of course it can implement the same functionality

Comment: A function pointer is only just that, a pointer to a function.  A function object is a full-blown object *and* has the ability to be used as a callable object.  Which one you choose -- you will know when the issue arises.  Your toy example isn't one of those scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"State" refers to data that is remembered and carried between subsequent calls to a function or class method.

Your `MyFuncPtr` is stateful, as it carries a data member `a` whose value is set in `MyFuncPtr`'s constructor and is remembered and used through all calls to `MyFuncPtr::operator()`.  You are setting the state once, and then using it over and over.  You could just as easily update the state instead, by have `MyFuncPtr::operator()` save the new value into `a` and then expose another class method to retrieve the current value of `a` when needed.

In your example, `sum()` is also stateful, as it is not a free function, it is actually a non-static member of `MyFuncPtr`, and thus has access to the same state data (`MyFuncPtr::a`) that `MyFuncPtr::operator()` has access to.  A better example of a stateless `sum()` would look more like this instead:

```cpp
class MyFuncPtr
{
public:
    int a;

    int operator ()(int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
    
    MyFuncPtr(int val)
    {
        a = val;
    }
};

int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!\n";

    MyFuncPtr obj(5);
    cout << obj(15) << endl;

    cout << sum(5, 15) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Remy Lebeau,that solves my confusion on functors having state.But here is another doubt that I have as in my code example if the normal member method is doing the same that functor is providing what exactly is the advantage of using functors except functor provide inline functionality which other method doesn't provide.Is there any other advantage than it?

Comment: A functor is simply an object that has overridden `operator()` so the object can be called with function-like syntax, in contexts where a function-like call needs to be made (for instance, in callbacks to standard algorithms). You can use non-operator class methods for that same purpose if you wrap them, for instance with a lambda or `std::bind()`.

Answer (score 3):

The word *functor* refers to the whole class `MyFuncPtr`, not only `operator()` in it.

What is meant by normal functions not having state is that a *free* function cannot retain state between function calls, not that a member function can't.

However even that is not fully true, since normal functions can have static local variables which do retain some global state scoped locally to the function and they may also access global variables without them being passed as parameter, which can serve as state scoped outside the function itself.

State can also be maintained by any function via a contract with the caller to pass state through the return value or output parameters of the function back to it as input parameters.

Also, functors *can* have state, they do not need to.

Comment: Normal functions that use static variables are evil and should be avoided.

Comment: Normal functions can have output parameters that return stateful data meant to be passed back in on subsequent calls.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have added that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau a functor is often used in a context where you don't have control of the parameter sequence. My favorite use for it is in `std::sort` where your functor can have a member that tells you which field of a structure should be used for the comparison.

Comment: @MarkRansom I know what a functor is, and how it is used. In your `sort()` example, a lambda is typically better to use than a manual functor.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm having trouble imagining how a lambda would work better for my sorting example than a functor.  Do you have a good example to point me to?

Comment: Instead of something like: `struct myFunctor { int which; myFunctor(int which) : which(which) { } bool operator()(const myStruct &item, const myStruct &item2) const { /* use which as needed */ return ...; } }; std::sort(..., myFunctor(...));` you can use this instead: `int which = ...; std::sort(..., [=](const auto &item, const auto &item2){ /* use which as needed */ return ...; });`